# find list of higgest value in row and get colum name of them

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

my input:

```
df <- data.frame("foo"=1, "bar"=2, "baz"=3, "gaz"=12, "taz"=14, "paz"=4)
```

I want get 3 higgest value in first row and columnname where they are. So I expect get something like this `taz`,`gaz`,`paz`.
I trying `pmax`, `slice_max` without success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data.frame is really only one row, you could use

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  slice_max(value, n = 3)
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  name  value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 taz      14
2 gaz      12
3 paz       4
```

Otherwise you either have to do some filtering or use a row number combined with some grouping.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option with `apply` to do this for every row in `df`.

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) names(head(sort(x, decreasing = TRUE), 3)))

#      [,1] 
#[1,] "taz"
#[2,] "gaz"
#[3,] "paz"
```

If you need both the value and column name you may return a list.

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  x <- head(sort(x, decreasing = TRUE), 3)
  list(value = as.numeric(x), name = names(x))
})

#[[1]]
#[[1]]$value
#[1] 14 12  4

#[[1]]$name
#[1] "taz" "gaz" "paz"
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use `stack` with `order` in `base R`

```
out <- stack(df)[2:1]
head(out[order(-out$values),], 3)
  ind values
5 taz     14
4 gaz     12
6 paz      4
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try this

```
> df[order(-unlist(df))[1:3]]
  taz gaz paz
1  14  12   4
```